# Equal width on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I have two boxes, it looks like this

```html
<div class="dataViewBox">
  <div class="dataViewBox-Download">
    <div class="dataViewBox-DownloadLink">
      <span class="dataViewBox-Hashes"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="testblock0h" class="dataViewBox-HideShowButton" onclick="magicmushrooms('testblock0')">Show</div>

    <div class="dataViewBox-Name">SomeName</div>
  </div>

  <div id="testblock0" class="dataViewBox-BottomBorder">
    <div id="test0" class="dataViewBox-Data toggleable Text">
        <span>this is just a test to show the the box can expand and be alot more bigger then it first was</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="infoViewExpirein">
  <div id="infoViewExpireinTime">Build this up to be bigger then the box................................</div>
</div>

<div class="dataViewBox">
  <div class="dataViewBox-Download">
    <div class="dataViewBox-DownloadLink">
      <span class="dataViewBox-Hashes"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="testblock1h" class="dataViewBox-HideShowButton" onclick="magicmushrooms('testblock1')">Show</div>

    <div class="dataViewBox-Name">SomeName</div>
  </div>

  <div id="testblock1" class="dataViewBox-BottomBorder">
    <div id="test1" class="dataViewBox-Data toggleable Text">
        <span>See how this box fallows the other one when you open it, and same when you close it, it always has equal width</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="infoViewExpirein">
  <div id="infoViewExpireinTime">Build this up to be bigger then the box................................</div>
</div>
```

All the code is too much to post here, but I have two boxes, the code works as it is now but the thing is that I do not like how I have solved this problem, if you open one box and you'll see at the other comes free with and the same size, it's the idea that it should be so. So all elements on the page is always symmetric. Its just that it only works if you have "display: table" And i try to find another way to do this whit same results, its always hard when you try to get equal width on everything, But the way to do it CSS/JavaScript does not matter. So question is can i get same result whitout "display: table"?

Link: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuee3/)

/ Slaktarn

Comment: @Whiskey: That's just an automated message. We reuse the duplicate post functionality here because you reposted your question, *which you should not do*. You can edit your original to improve it to renew attention for it, instead.